# Single dependency directory for different projects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a few really small Node.js projects. Would like to have a separate directory for node modules so all those projects can require from same location. I am trying to minimize the storage space. Working on many small "tutorial projects" and seems stupid to install the same module multiple times.

Here is the example structure

```
├── shared_directory
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── package-lock.json
├── project_1
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── style.css
├── project_2
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── style.css
```

It seems like am calling require() with a wrong attribute or wrong path.

```js
// project_1 app.js

const express = require("../shared_directory/express");
const bodyParser = require("../shared_directory/body-parser");
```

```
    Error: Cannot find module '../shared_directory/express'
```

Comment: What's the context, why do you want to do that? Maybe you want e.g. npm workspaces (which keep the dependencies in a parent directory so Node's module search finds them) or perhaps pnpm (which manages dependencies by symlink).

Comment: Just trying to minimize the storage space. Working on many small "tutorial projects" and seems stupid to install same module multiple times.

Comment: Then consider pnpm, each unique dependency is stored once and synlinked where it's needed to make it _"disk space efficient "_: https://pnpm.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm workspaces, it allows you to manage multiple packages or projects within a single top-level root package.

Each package has its own `package.json` file. and it is smart enough to scan your folders looking for all dependencies to install. You can also define dependencies at the root level, and they can be shared among all the packages within the workspace.

```
root
│ node_modules
│ package.json
│ package-lock.json
├── project_1
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── package.json # Dependencies: lodash
│   └── style.css
├── project_2
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── package.json # Dependencies: lodash
│   ├── style.css
```

You can easily find a way to setup workspace in your project online

Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces